# how to get from_str_radix to recognize a negative hex number

Tags: rust

This code

```
fn main() {
   let hex="ffffffff";
   let num = i32::from_str_radix(hex,16).unwrap();
   println!("{}", num);
}
```

fails saying that the resulting number is too large to fit in an i32

the inverse

```
println!("{:08x}", -1i32);
```

however produces 'ffffffff'

Is there something simple I am missing or do I have to get into bit trickery

Comment: Does it even make sense to have a negative hex number?  That's suddenly relying on processor architecture and integer implementation details.  The maximum hex value for an `i32` is `0x7f_ff_ff_ff`.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Hex is just base 16, and base 16 can have negative numbers just like base 10 can. However, in this case a positive hex number is being parsed. That is to say, something like `"-a"` should produce the result -10 (and [it does](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8b58503c5790152e3758e1a3b08e6837)) but that isn't what's being attempted here.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley println! seems to think that -1 is FFFFFFF, and every processor I know seems to think that a 32 bit signed value of all 1s (ie ffffffff) is -1

Answer (score 5):

When you ask `from_str_radix` to parse a number, you're not asking it to parse a bit pattern, but a number.  Most people would not expect this to work with a base 10 number:

```
fn main() {
    let hex = "4294967295";
    let num = i32::from_str_radix(hex, 10).unwrap();
    println!("{}", num);
}
```

Having consistent behaviour is important, and this check is very valuable when parsing data formats.

If you want to do this, then the way to do that is to read it as a `u32` and convert it:

```
fn main() {
    let hex = "ffffffff";
    let num = u32::from_str_radix(hex, 16).unwrap() as i32;
    println!("{}", num);
}
```

That prints `-1`, as you expect.  Of course, that will not handle numbers with a minus sign.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this function can indeed parse negative hex numbers such as `"-a"`, but the code in the question contains a positive hex number. So the title of the question and the code in the question don't really match up, which is confusing, because the answer to the question in the title is "well, it _can_ do that."

Comment: i am just surprised at the asymmetry between from_str_radix and println!,